# React native - import the whole file / split js code into several files

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Basically I want to split the react-native code into **several js files**. I have my main '*index.ios.js*' file. I moved some code (*MainComponent* class) to another file: './iOSCode/main.js'

How can I import the whole '*./iOSCode/main.js*' file content into '*index.ios.js*'?

I tried:

```
import { MainComponent as MainComponent }  from './iOSCode/main.js';

and

import MainComponent from './iOSCode/main.js';
```

with no luck...

I get an error:

```
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or  class/function [...] but got: undefined
intantiateReactComponent.js:70
instantiateChild   ReactChildReconciler.js:45
```

==========

EDIT:

As of @ Jagadish Upadhyay suggestion I was missing the **export** statement near MainComponent class inside './iOSCode/main.js'

Code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  ListView
} from 'react-native';

export class MainComponent extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <Text> abc </Text>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you exported the class? Can you post the code?

Comment: Yes, I was missing the 'export' statement in MainComponent class. Thanks. 
Is there still a method to import the whole file? not just one class from './iOSCode/main.js'??

Comment: @kosiara-BartoszKosarzycki there is a way to import all exports, if that's what you mean... if you export 2 classes, for instance, you could type `import * as NameOfModule from 'main'` and `NameOfModule` would contain all of the exports

Comment: Thanks, I used your comment to separate styles into 'styles.js'

Answer (score 4):

To separate out a class you need to add the **export** statement and use this import format:

```
import { MainComponent as MainComponent }  from './iOSCode/main.js';
```

You can also move out styles into a separate file.

styles.js:

```
import {
  StyleSheet
} from 'react-native';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({

  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
});

module.exports = styles;
```

and use this import in the main js file:

```
import * as styles from './styles.js';
```

Remember to add:  'module.exports = styles;'